# Unable to re-render HTML generated with PrismJS in Angular app

Tags: angular

How to use PrismJS with Angular/cli App.
I have installed the prismjs package using npm.

app.component.ts

```
var Prism = require('prismjs');
.
.
.
this.code_c = Prism.highlight(data, Prism.languages.clike);
```

template.html

```
<div>
    {{code_c}}
</div>
```

`code_c` is fetched using Github pubic API. code_c is loaded after the page finishes loading. I do get generated HTML but it's not rendered as HTML it shows plain text as in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: https://schier.co/blog/2013/01/07/how-to-re-run-prismjs-on-ajax-content.html

Comment: In this case you need to use `innerHTML` like `<div [innerHTML]="code_c"></div>` and maybe wrap in `pre` and `code` tag

Comment: As i said try using `innetHTML`

Comment: It worked Thanks @yurzui.

Comment: Hey @yurzui it's working for `clike` and `javascript` only, can you please tell me how to use it for python and go syntax highlighting.